# Svelte Node Adapter Sendgrid issue TypeError: sg.setApiKey is not a function

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm building a node webserver with `Svelte` with the node adapter (typescript).
I'm trying to send an email using `@sendgrid/mail`. Here's how I'm doing it:

```js
import * as sg from "@sendgrid/mail";

export function SendMail(mailData : MailDataFormat) {
  sg.setApiKey("secret_from_env")
  ...
}
```

this works fine from `npm run dev`, but on the final build (and in `npm run preview`) it throws this error:

`TypeError: sg.setApiKey is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working.

```
-import * as sg from '@sendgrid/mail';
+import mailService from '@sendgrid/mail';

export function SendMail(mailData : MailDataFormat) {
-    sg.setApiKey(env.SG_KEY);
+    mailService.setApiKey(env.SG_KEY);
     ...
}
```

I feel like I fell into a black hole because all existing documentation uses the include() syntax. Still not sure what the actual cause of this issue was.